# Why can I load a class from a JAR but not a resource?

Tags: java, classpath, manifest.mf, resource-loading

I'm using a JAR which contains only a `ClassPath` element to build the classpath for my Java app and I've encountered a weird behavior: I can load classes from the JARs mentioned in the `ClassPath` element but some (or all) resources are missing.

Example: My `full-classpath.jar` contains just a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with the usual content and this line:

```
ClassPath: foo-service.jar bar-service.jar service-main.jar
```

`service-main.jar` contains `com.pany.project.Main`.

When I run `java -cp full-classpath.jar com.pany.project.Main`, that works.

But `foo-service.jar` and `bar-service.jar` contain service definitions in `META-INF/services/....`

When I invoke `java.util.ServiceLoader` from a Maven unit test, it can see both the `foo` and the `bar` service. When I `java -cp full-classpath.jar com.pany.project.Main -service foo`, I see an empty service list in my log.

Worse, when I call `Main.class.getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`, I get only the manifest from `full-classpath.jar`. The manifest files from the other three JARs are missing which doesn't make sense since I can load classes from those JARs! It also works when I build the whole classpath manually. It only fails when I use the `ClassPath` element in the `full-classpath.jar`.

Any ideas what could be wrong or how I could debug this?

I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest attribute `Class-Path` is handled in `sun.misc.URLClassPath.JarLoader.parseClassPath(URL, String)`. This method is called once from `sun.misc.URLClassPath.JarLoader.getClassPath()`. At the start of `getClassPath()`, you can find this code:

```
        if (index != null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (metaIndex != null) {
            return null;
        }
```

which means: If your classpath JAR contains an index or "meta index" (whatever that is), the `Class-Path` attribute is ignored.

I can't tell why Java can still load classes from JARs mentioned in the `Class-Path` attribute but deleting the index fixes the resource loading problem.